# Making overflowing div position to bottom parent div

Tags: html, css

I have this DIV with a height of 30px; and a fixed position.
I have been looking for a way to position the overflowing div to the bottom of parent DIV
see diagram and code:
[image: Over flow div diagram]

Here is my code so far:

```
 <div style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left: 0; height:40px; overflow:visible; border:solid gray 1px;">
    <div style="border:solid #999 1px; height: 275px; background-color: #ffffff; margin: 5px; float:left;"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATED:**
Here is how it should look like if I add another div. That is why I cant use absolute position on child div:
[image]

Comment: the outer div is the parent you're talking about?

Comment: yes sir.. it is the parent element

Comment: Thanks for wanting to mark this question as solved. We don't do that by editing titles here, though - the green tick mark against the preferred answer is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For almost 5 hours of finding solution I finally come up with one which really suites my needs..
**Sir anurupr's Answer:**
It did worked great how ever the problem with his answer is that if I try to re-size a child div to "lets say 30px" while other sibling div is 275px the smallest div will not stick to the footer.

**Sir extramaster's Answer:**
Is really powerful and I really believe that it would look great how ever ie9 and below does not support flexible-box.

**SOLUTION:**
So I have come up with a solution that I believe would work great.Here is my Code:

```
<div class="row-fluid" style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left: 0; height:30px; overflow:visible; border:solid gray 1px;">
    <div class="span3" style="position:relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:275px; background-color: #ffffff; bottom:0; border:#000 1px solid;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="position:relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:35px; background-color: #ffffff; bottom:0; border:#000 1px solid;"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="span3" style="position:relative;">
        <div style="position:absolute; width:100%; height:275px; background-color: #ffffff; bottom:0; border:#000 1px solid;"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is a link to see demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/drowndown/wXC5R/)

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the `position` of the inner `div` as `absolute` and `bottom` to `0`

For making the child divs to float left as well you need to use a container div encapsulating the child divs

like this

```
    <!-- container div -->    
    <div style="border:solid #999 1px; height: 275px; background-color: #ffffff;position:absolute; width:100%;bottom:0;">
        <!-- child div 1 -->
        <div style="border:solid #999 1px; height: 275px; background-color: #ffffff;float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
        <!-- child div 2 -->
        <div style="border:solid #999 1px; height: 275px; background-color: #ffffff;float:left;width:100%;height:100%;"></div>
</div>
```

check this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/9Yg47/2/

Comment: i set the width for it just to show the div clearly. you can remove that if you like

Comment: the problem with this is: If I add another div it will overlap its siblings.I need a way of doing it without absolute positioning of the child div .Is there another way ?

Comment: @NEWBIE: What result are you expecting after add one or more child divs?

Comment: i updated the answer as well as the fiddle . try it out

Comment: it does fit to the bottom of the parent div and work so well how ever I still have another problem I need the child divs to always stick to bottom of parent div so when I resize the height it will stick to the bottom

Comment: resize the height of child divs or the parent div?

Comment: child div sir.. I submitted an answer please feel free to correct me.. thnx

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question!

## Why this is interesting

Previously this question wouldn't be at all possible to answer, and considered quite impossible without javascript and/or by setting a predefined width for css.

So this is where web technology has evidently progressed, instead of using tables, floats, javascript, predefined width elements, only with a little bit of css3 magic, the goal in your question is achievable...

## The CSS3 solution

Using **flex-boxes** (a technology recently introduced in most modern browsers), you can easily having floating child elements out of a parent element that's fix-aligned..

You can define a flex-box with: `display: flex;` and introduce floating content with `flex: 1;`

### The HTML structure

The following code defines the structure that this answer (and demos) will be using:

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Wowww! The power of CSS3 is awesome</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

`#parent` is the containers that is to be fixed at the bottom, the role of `.child` will be explored later and everything inside `.child-content` is to be the stuff you see poking out of parent.

### The CSS to be used

```
#parent {
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0;
    left: 0;
    height:40px;
    overflow:visible;
    border:solid #000 1px;
    width:100%;
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: -moz-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
    margin: 0px 0px 0px -20px;
}
.child {
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -webkit-flex: 1;
    -moz-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;
    margin-right:10px;
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
.child-content {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    border:solid #000 1px;
    background-color:#fff;
    height:104px;
    width:100%;
}
.actual-child-content {
    padding:10px;
}
```

Both `#parent`, and `.child` contribute to to making the box what it is.
`.child-content` deals with breaking `.child` out of the predefined height of `#parent` and "overflow" the body. `#parent` is the container situated at the bottom and `.child` are the boxes that will have evenly divided contents (depending on how many there are)

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9PPE/show/) | [Source](http://jsfiddle.net/z9PPE/)
[image: One box]

### More then just a box

So what about floating a second box at the bottom inside `#parent`?

Well, since css3 is all powerful and flex-boxes a dream to developers nowadays, to add another box next to the first you can simply add another `.child` element to `#parent`.

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Wowww! The power of CSS3 is awesome</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Wow, a second box that's floating fine!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And boom, you have basically what is a grid based system, instead of messy hacks involving floats and javascript and setting predefined widths.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9PPE/1/show/) 
[image: Two box]

In fact, that one css code is so powerful that you can simply reuse it for more child boxes...

```
<div id="parent">
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Wowww! The power of CSS3 is awesome</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Wow, a second box that's floating fine!</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="child">
        <div class="child-content">
            <div class="actual-child-content">Man, this is powerful.....</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/z9PPE/2/show/)
[image: Three box]

They all float fine! Goodbye the old and dark ages of setting a div with a table property, or by using ***shudders*** tables....

[Bonus](http://jsfiddle.net/z9PPE/3/show/)

Comment: Hello Sir thank you for your effort of helping I truly appreciate it.. how ever the problem with this solution is that it is not compatible with ie9 and below.. So I have come up with a solution please dont hesitate to view and correct me.. thnx